# java chat application not working on other machines

Tags: java, networking

I have made a basic chat application which runs fine on the same PC but I want it to work on different machines as well.

For the sake of simplicity, I have omitted the GUI code. I receive the IP, name, and port from a separate application which passes it to the client's constructor. I have entered the IP and port of the machine on which the server is running.

**Client**

```
public class ClientGui extends JFrame implements Runnable, KeyListener, ActionListener
{
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private Socket socket;
    private String name , ip;
    private int port;
    private JTextField input;
    private JTextArea console;

    private JButton send;
    private String message;
    private DateFormat format;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private String reply;

    public ClientGui(String name, String ip, int port)
    {
        format = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT);

        this.name = name;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;

        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            while (true) {
                out.println(name);
                reply = in.readLine();

                if (reply.equals("NAME")) {
                    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name taken , Enter another");
                } else {
                    input.setEditable(true);
                    setTitle(name);
                    break;
                }
            }

            while (true) {
                reply = in.readLine();

                if (reply.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                    log(reply.substring(7));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                out.close();
                in.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Server implements Runnable
{
    private static ArrayList<PrintWriter> writers;
    private static HashSet<String> names;
    private Socket socket;
    private String name;
    private String message;

    public Server(Socket socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        PrintWriter temp = null;

        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
            try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true)) {
                while (true) {
                    name = in.readLine();

                    if (names.contains(name)) {
                        out.println("NAME");
                    } else {
                        out.println("NAMEACCEPTED");
                        names.add(name);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                writers.add(out);
                temp = out;

                while(true) {
                    message = in.readLine();

                    for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE" + name + " : " + message);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                names.remove(name);
                writers.remove(temp);
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        writers = new ArrayList<>();
        names = new HashSet<>();
        ServerSocket server = null;

        try {
            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid port");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for clients....");
                new Thread(new Server(server.accept())).start();
                System.out.println("Client Received");  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Server can't accept clients");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the network bit works? Does the client connect to the server at all?

Comment: yes it does when client and server are on the same machine

Comment: Check if there isn't a firewall blocking the networking, also check if you bind to the right network interface. If you bind to 0.0.0.0, it should listen on all network interfaces.The problem is most likely not your code, but rather the network bit of your code or the settings of your computer.

Comment: i have tried another java chat application (not my code) and it ran on all computers just fine

Comment: If you're using TCP, maybe install wireshark to identify what is happening.

Comment: This sounds like a firewall issue to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the inconvenience to all

the problem was with the port i was using when i switched it , it worked on different machines

thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be, because
1) you haven't installed the rigth jre-Version on both devices
2) you aren't in the same Network or you haven't forwarded you'r Ip

have you tried to use this in a Virtual box?

(client1 == vbox1, Server == Computer, client2 == vbox2)

hopefully, this helped

Comment: i have tried another java chat application (not my code) and it ran on all computers just fine

Comment: ok. Are you sure, your Server has enough free space allocated?